# How to display a placeholder while the image is loaded in Next.Js?

Tags: next.js, nextjs-image

I'm getting some images from Firebase using getStaticProps, and then displaying them with next Image component. However, they take a while to display, how can I display a placeholder while they haven't loaded?

Comment: Can you please share the code you currently have?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

There is an experimental merged [pull request](https://github.com/vercel/next.js/pull/24153) on thery `@canary` branch. If you want to try it out just update your nextjs version on the latest canary released.
Just add a new `placeholder="blur"` props on the `Image` component.

Or you can use this [package](https://github.com/joe-bell/plaiceholder).

Edit: Nextjs 11 now has officially released the `placeholder='blur'` props for the `<Image>` component. You can read [here](https://nextjs.org/blog/next-11#image-improvements) more about this image placeholders. Make sure you update your nextjs, react, react-dom versions by running `npm i next@latest react@latest react-dom@latest`

Answer (score 6):

use `placeholder` property, a placeholder to use while the image is loading, possible values are `blur` or `empty`. Defaults to `empty`.

When `blur`, the `blurDataURL` property will be used as the placeholder. If `src` is an object from a static import and the imported image is jpg, png, or webp, then `blurDataURL` will automatically be populated.

notice that for dynamic images, you **must** provide the `blurDataURL` property.
the contents of "blurDataURL" property should be a small Data URL to represent the image.